# White line bug using Colormatrix

Tags: android, bitmap, colormatrix

So I have a HUGE problem. I can't solve it for years so please anybody who can help - it would be amazing.
So the problem is with ColorMatrix. As you can see in the picture when I add the effect on the photo and save it to my memory I get that kind of picture with a little white line in the left. The funny fact is that when I increase contrast for example to 7 this line became more and more bigger. So the problem as I guess is with contrast and brightness. Anyway it works great and with anything else I'm satisfied...just only this one bug which will kill me someday I guess. Any help?
My code:

```
public void effect(View view) {
    float contrast = 1;
    float brightness = 0;


    Bitmap.Config config = bmp.getConfig();
    if (config == null) {
        config = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    }

    operation = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), config);


    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix(new float[]
            {
                    contrast, 0, 0, 0, brightness,
                    0, contrast, 0, 0, brightness,
                    0, 0, contrast, 0, brightness,
                    0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 1
            });
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(operation);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, contrast, brightness, paint);

    imageview.setImageBitmap(operation);


}
```

[IMAGE OF BUG. The white line in the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nosR8.jpg)

Anyone who will help with this. THANK YOU!

Comment: what is the hidden idea of passing `contrast` and `brightness` as `x` and `y` in `canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, contrast, brightness, paint)`?

Comment: @pskink I learned at school that I need to write like this in the end. What's your offer? I would be really thankful if you would share your minds how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I want to post the answer to my problem.
I was so dumb..- x and y have to be 0 0 instead of writing contrast and brightness.

Solved line:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, paint);
```